# How to use a dynamic id variable in a template.find(input:hidden[id='SOME VARIABLE']) declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

I wanna know if it's possible do something like this:

In HTML I have:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{productName}}" id="{{productId}}">
<button type="button" class="buyProduct" value="{{productId}}">Buy</button>
```

In Javascript (Meteor) I wanna do:

```
Template.productsList.events({
    click .buyProduct: function(event, template){
        var idGeneratedByBtnClick = event.target.value;
        console.log(idGeneratedByBtnClick); // it shows the correct ID for each button
        var element = template.find('input:hidden[id='idGeneratedByBtnClick']');
});
```

Can i use a variable like this: `input:hidden[id='My Variable here']` ???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's available to use the variable as string.
Could you try?

```
var idGeneratedByBtnClick = event.target.value;
var element = template.find('input:hidden[id=' + idGeneratedByBtnClick + ']');
```

Comment: It worked, thanks man. 

So many hours programming and my brain melted. I didn't thought about the '+' to concatenate lol

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. If it's ok, check resolved to my answer.